# Coldfusion 9 service crashing after I restart it

Tags: windows-server-2003, coldfusion

Anyone know what's going on?
Windows Server 2k3
Coldfusion9

I restarted the application service and it came back fine. Then a few minutes later it crashed. I can't figure out why it would crash after it restarted fine.

The event log shows:

```
Event Type: Information
Event Source:   ColdFusion 9 Application Server
Event Category: None
Event ID:   4
Date:       8/9/2012
Time:       12:24:07 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   270045-VM1
Description:
The ColdFusion 9 Application Server service for the "coldfusion" server was stopped.


Event Type: Information
Event Source:   UPHClean
Event Category: None
Event ID:   1401
Date:       8/9/2012
Time:       12:24:07 PM
User:       270045-VM1\[CF Username]
Computer:   270045-VM1
Description:
The following handles in user profile hive 270045-VM1\[CF Username] (S-1-5-21-3030763917-3778758062-1487362108-1014) have been remapped because they were preventing the profile from unloading successfully: 

jrun.exe (5084)
  HKCU (0x704)
  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer (0x1240)


For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.


Event Type: Information
Event Source:   ColdFusion 9 Application Server
Event Category: None
Event ID:   3
Date:       8/9/2012
Time:       12:24:07 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   270045-VM1
Description:
The ColdFusion 9 Application Server service for the "coldfusion" server was started.  PID is 2012.


Event Type: Warning
Event Source:   ColdFusion 9 Application Server
Event Category: None
Event ID:   80
Date:       8/9/2012
Time:       12:24:10 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   270045-VM1
Description:
The ColdFusion 9 Application Server service for the "coldfusion" server is restarting.


Event Type: Error
Event Source:   ColdFusion 9 Application Server
Event Category: None
Event ID:   259
Date:       8/9/2012
Time:       12:24:11 PM
User:       N/A
Computer:   270045-VM1
Description:
The ColdFusion 9 Application Server service could not be started.  Check the server "coldfusion" log files for more information.
```

The only logs in any CF log around that time are in the eventGateway.log:

```
"Information","Thread-1","08/09/12","12:24:07",,"Stopping Event Gateways."
"Information","Thread-1","08/09/12","12:24:07",,"Stopping Gateway: ID=Print CA, Class=coldfusion.eventgateway.cfml.CfmlGateway."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:44",,"Starting Event Backend Handlers."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:44",,"Initialized EventRequestDispatcher with a Thread Pool size of 1."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:44",,"Initializing EventRequestHandler"
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:44",,"Starting Event Gateways."
"Information","Thread-17","08/09/12","12:31:44",,"Starting Gateway: ID=Print CA, Class=coldfusion.eventgateway.cfml.CfmlGateway."
```

And Server.log:

```
"Information","Thread-1","08/09/12","12:24:12",,"ColdFusion stopped"
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:34",,"Starting logging..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:34",,"Starting license..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:37",,"Enterprise Edition enabled"
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:38",,"Starting crypto..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:38",,"Installed JSafe JCE provider: Version 3.6 RSA Security Inc. Crypto-J JCE Security Provider (implements RSA, DSA, Diffie-Hellman, AES, DES, Triple DES, DESX, RC2, RC4, RC5, PBE, MD2, MD5, RIPEMD160, SHA1, SHA224, SHA256, SHA384, SHA512, HMAC-MD5, HMAC-RIPEMD160, HMAC-SHA1, HMAC-SHA224, HMAC-SHA256, HMAC-SHA384, HMAC-SHA512)"
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:38",,"Starting security..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:39",,"Starting scheduler..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:39",,"Starting WatchService..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:39",,"Starting debugging..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:39",,"Starting sql..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:42",,"Pool Manager Started"
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:42",,"Starting mail..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:42",,"Starting runtime..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:42",,"CORBA Configuration not enabled"
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:42",,"Starting cron..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:42",,"Starting registry..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:43",,"Starting client..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:43",,"Starting xmlrpc..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:44",,"Starting graphing..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:44",,"Starting verity..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:44",,"Starting solr..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:44",,"Starting archive..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:44",,"Starting document..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:44",,"Starting eventgateway..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:44",,"Starting FlexAssembler..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:45",,"Starting .NET..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:45",,"Starting Monitoring..."
"Information","main","08/09/12","12:31:45",,"ColdFusion started"
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the account running the service. Also, I have had MASSIVE issues before with Cold Fusion storing all aplication variables in Windows Registry as default, leading to a registry becoming massive (2-5GB) and nothing working. Might be worth checking if this is enabled and if so, clear out all the reg entries.

Comment: @boburob - I'm not much of an expert on these things, where would I check that?

Comment: This is on IIS?

Comment: Yup IIS 6.0 [additional text to meet the character minimum]